# Determine if system is input-state stable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system, lyapunov-functions

I was trying to determine whether the following system is input-state stable (ISS):
\begin{align}
\dot{x_1} &= -x_1 + (1 - e^{x_2}) \\
\dot{x_2} &= -x_2 - u
\end{align}

I tried using the following Lyapunov function but with no luck:
\begin{equation}
V(x) = \frac{1}{2}x_1^2 + \frac{1}{2}x_2^2
\end{equation}

So I basically have to identify $\alpha_1(||x||)$, $\alpha_2(||x||)$, $W_3(x)$, $\rho(||x||)$

Any suggestions on how I could do it?

DEFINITION:
This is the condition that must be fulfilled for a system to be ISS
[image: Definition of ISS system]

Answer (score 1):

Your question is missing an assumption on $u$ so I assume it is bounded (otherwise checking ISS doesn't make sense).

Note that $\dot{x}_2$ does not depend on $x_1$, so the system $\dot{x}_2=-x_2 - u$ is ISS (stable LTI systems are always  ISS). This means $x_2$ is bounded for all $t$. Therefore $1 - e^{x_2}$ is also bounded for all $t$. So we can consider

$$
\dot{x}_1=-x_1+w
$$

where $w$ is a bounded input. This is again a stable LTI system with bounded input so it is ISS. Since this is more general, it also covers the "special" input $w=1-e^{x_2}$ (which is bounded as discussed before).

Therefore the whole system is ISS.